# access formatted value with special character in javascript array

Tags: javascript, rest, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

I am getting an object as response for an api call

The object looks like below

[image]

Now when I try `response._modifiedby_value` I am getting the right response, but when I try `response.createdby_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue` I am getting the below error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError {message: "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because '@' is a special character, therefore you can't do:

```
response.createdby_value@OData = 2;
```

but instead

```
response["createdby_value@OData"] = 2;
```